# A question about integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ a (finite, if necessary) measure space.
$f\in L_1(\mu), A\in\Sigma$.

I wanna find $B\subset A, B\in \Sigma$ such that $|\int_B f\,d\mu|\ge \frac{1}{4} \int_A|f|\,d\mu$.
This is easy for if $f$ is real-valued since we can divide $A$ by two parts: $f\ge0$ and $f < 0$ and the inequality even holds for coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$. However, I can't do for complex-valued function. If I do the similar things, the coefficient becomes $\frac{1}{8}$. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a complex-valued function. We denote $g=\text{Re} f$ and $h=\text{Im} f$. As $|f|\leq g^++g^-+h^++h^-$ then 
$$\int_A|f|\leq \int_Ag^++\int_Ag^-+\int_Ah^++\int_Ah^-\leq4\max\left(\int_Ag^+,\int_Ag^-,\int_Ah^+,\int_Ah^-\right).$$
If we suppose that $\max\left(\int_Ag^+,\int_Ag^-,\int_Ah^+,\int_Ah^-\right)=\int_Ag^+$ then
$$\int_A|f|\leq4\int_Ag^+=\int_Ag1_{\{g\geq0\}}=4\int_{A\cap\{g\geq0\}}g=4\left|\int_Bg\right|\leq4\left|\int_Bf\right|$$
with $B=A\cap\{g\geq0\}\subset A$ and belongs to $\Sigma$.